# Line adjustment In TOC/LOF

Tags: table-of-contents

In my TOC and LOF, the items should be adjusted such that the word should reach the right margin and avoiding space before go into new line and then new line start exactly where the first line begins.(Check out what i got in the latex)

[image: My latex output]

This is the whole parts of my style file;(report class)

```
%%
%%
%%
\typeout{Thesis style for IGSR Mediterranean University, Version 1.0}
%
% Definitions for title and approval pages
%
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
%\def\program#1{\gdef\@program{#1}}
\def\Dept#1{\gdef\@Dept{#1}}
\def\subyear#1{\gdef\@subyear{#1}}
\def\InstituteDirector#1{\gdef\@InstituteDirector{#1}}
\def\DeptChair#1{\gdef\@DeptChair{#1}}
\def\cosuperi#1{\gdef\@cosuperi{#1}}
\def\cosuperii#1{\gdef\@cosuperii{#1}}
\def\examineri#1{\gdef\@examineri{#1}}
\def\examinerii#1{\gdef\@examinerii{#1}}
\def\supervisor#1{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}
\def\examineriii#1{\gdef\@examineriii{#1}}
\def\examineriv#1{\gdef\@examineriv{#1}}
\def\examinerv#1{\gdef\@examinerv{#1}}
\def\dateofapproval#1{\gdef\@dateofapproval{#1}}
%
\global\let\@degree\empty
%\global\let\@program\empty
\global\let\@Dept\empty
\global\let\@InstituteDirector\empty
\global\let\@DeptChair\empty
\global\let\@cosuperi\empty
\global\let\@cosuperii\empty
\global\let\@examineri\empty
\global\let\@examinerii\empty
\global\let\@supervisor\empty
\global\let\@examineriii\empty
\global\let\@examineriv\empty
\global\let\@examinerv\empty
\global\let\@examinervi\empty
\global\let\@dateofapproval\empty
\def\nyear{\number\year}
\def\nmonth{\number\month}
\global\let\@subyear\nyear
\global\let\@submonth\nmonth
%
% Other definitions
%
\xdef\@singlespaced{1}
\xdef\@onehalfspaced{1.5}
%
\newlength{\insd}
\newlength{\dc}
\newlength{\dpt}
\newlength{\spv}
\newlength{\ei}
\newlength{\csi}
\newlength{\csii}
\newlength{\eii}
\newlength{\eiii}
\newlength{\eiv}
\newlength{\ev}
\let\@app\empty
\newcounter{thsfootcnt}
%
% Title page
%
\newcommand\uptitle{
  \ifx\@degree\empty \@@warning{No \string\degree\space given} \fi
  \null
  \vspace*{-45pt}
  \let\baselinestretch\@singlespaced{\fontsize{18.3}{1}{\textbf{\@title}} \\% %title font size
  \vskip 160pt                                                   %distance between title and author
  \fontsize{16.4}{1}{\textbf{\@author}} \\ %Author font size
  \vskip 110pt
  \large{Submitted to the\\Institute of Graduate Studies and Research\\            %%\large with the document class of 12pt corresponds to fontsize 14.4
  in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of} \\[120pt]}}
%\vskip 200pt
\newcommand\downtitle{
\vskip 120pt
 %\vskip 2\baselineskip
\let\baselinestretch\@singlespaced{
\vskip 00pt
  \large{Eastern Mediterranean University} \\ \large{August 2017}}\\[1pt] \large{Gazimagusa, North Cyprus}
  \null}
%
\newcommand\relaxtitlestuff{
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax}
%
\newcommand\makemstitle{\begin{titlepage}
   \let\baselinestretch\@singlespaced{
   \begin{center}
   \uptitle
   \vskip 56pt
   \large{Master of Science \\ in \\ \@Dept}
   \downtitle
   \end{center}}
   \end{titlepage}
   \relaxtitlestuff}
%

\newcommand\makephdtitle{\begin{titlepage}
   \begin{center}
   \uptitle
   \large{Doctor of Philosophy} \\% \vspace{-0.5cm}
   \large{in}\\ %\vspace{-0.5cm}
   \large{\@Dept}
   \downtitle
   \end{center}
   \end{titlepage}
   \relaxtitlestuff}
%
% Approval page
%
\newcommand\makeapprovalpage{%
  \addtocounter{page}{-1}
  \settowidth{\insd}{\@InstituteDirector}
  \settowidth{\dc}{\@DeptChair}
  \settowidth{\dpt}{\@Dept}
  \settowidth{\ei}{\@examineri}
  \settowidth{\csi}{\@cosuperi}
  \settowidth{\csii}{\@cosuperii}
  \settowidth{\eii}{\@examinerii}
  \settowidth{\spv}{\@supervisor}
  \settowidth{\eiii}{\@examineriii}
  \settowidth{\eiv}{\@examineriv}
  \settowidth{\ev}{\@examinerv}
  \ifdim\ei>\spv \spv\ei \fi
  \ifdim\csii>\spv \spv\ei \fi
  \ifdim\eii>\spv \spv\eii \fi
  \ifdim\csi>\spv \spv\ei \fi
  \ifdim\eiii>\spv \spv\eiii \fi
  \ifdim\eiv>\spv \spv\eiv \fi
  \ifdim\ev>\spv \spv\ev \fi
  \vspace*{-1.6cm}
  \hspace{-0.5cm}Approval of the Institute of Graduate Studies and Research
  \vspace*{1cm}
  \begin{tabbing}
  \hspace*{3.0cm} \= \hspace*{\spv}\hspace*{1em} \= \kill
  \ifx\@InstituteDirector\empty \ifx\@cosuperi\empty \ifx\@cosuperi\empty
     \@@warning{No \string\InstituteDirector\space given} \fi \fi
  \else \hspace*{8.cm}\makebox[60mm]\hrulefill\> \\[-16pt]\hspace*{8.5cm}\@InstituteDirector \>  \\[-16pt]
     \>\hspace*{7.5cm} Director \\\\ \> \fi
  \hspace{-3.1cm}\vspace*{6cm}I certify that this thesis satisfies the requirements as a
  thesis for the degree of Doctor\\[-12pt]
  of Philosophy in \@Dept.\\[1cm]
  \vspace*{-0.5cm}
  \ifx\@supervisor\empty \ifx\@cosuperi\empty \ifx\@cosuperi\empty
     \@@warning{No \string\supervisor\space given} \fi \fi
  \else \hspace*{7.9cm}\makebox[60mm]\hrulefill\> \\[-16pt]\hspace*{8.3cm}\@DeptChair\>  \\[-16pt]
     \>\hspace*{4.8cm} Chair, Department of Electrical and\>\\[-16pt]                                                                               %\hspace value can be change to change the position of expression"Electrical Engineering"
     \>\hspace*{5.8cm} Electronic Engineering\\[1cm]\> \fi
  \hspace{-3.1cm}We certify that we have read this thesis and that in our opinion it is fully adequate,\\[-12pt]
  in scope and quality as a thesis of the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in Electrical \\[-12pt]
 and Electronic Engineering.\\[1cm]

  \ifx\@supervisor\empty \else \hspace*{8.1cm}\makebox[60mm]\hrulefill\> \\[-16pt]\hspace*{9cm}\@supervisor \> \\[-16pt]
     \>\hspace*{7cm} Supervisor  \> \\[-1.9cm]

  \hspace*{-0.0cm}\makebox[60mm]\hrulefill\> \\[-16pt]\hspace*{0.90cm}\@cosuperi \>
  \\[-16pt]
     \>\hspace*{-1.5cm} Cosupervisor \\ \>\\\\\fi
  \hspace*{10cm}Examining Committee\\*[-24pt]
  \makebox[14cm]\hrulefill\\

  \ifx\@examineri\empty \else   1. \@examineri \>   \hspace*{5cm}\makebox[60mm]\hrulefill \\ \fi
  \ifx\@examinerii\empty \else  2. \@examinerii \>  \hspace*{5cm}\makebox[60mm]\hrulefill\\ \fi
  \ifx\@examineriii\empty \else 3. \@examineriii \> \hspace*{5cm}\makebox[60mm]\hrulefill\\ \fi
  4. \@supervisor \> \hspace*{5cm}\makebox[60mm]\hrulefill \\
  \ifx\@examineriv\empty \else  5. \@examineriv \>  \hspace*{5cm}\makebox[60mm]\hrulefill\\ \fi
  \end{tabbing}
  \vfill
  %\vspace*{2cm}
%\global\let\@title\@empty
%\global\let\title\relax
\global\let\@dateofapproval\@empty
\global\let\dateofapproval\relax
\global\let\@supervisor\@empty
\global\let\supervisor\relax
\global\let\@cosuperi\@empty
\global\let\cosuperi\relax
\global\let\@cosuperii\@empty
\global\let\cosuperii\relax
\global\let\@examineri\@empty
\global\let\examineri\relax
\global\let\@examinerii\@empty
\global\let\examinerii\relax
\global\let\@examineriii\@empty
\global\let\examinerii\relax
\global\let\@examinervi\@empty
\global\let\examinervi\relax
\global\let\@examinerv\@empty
\global\let\examinerv\relax
}
%
% Abstract, Acknowledgements, Oz, etc.
%

\newenvironment{preface}{\chapter*{\prefacename}}
   {\par\vfil\null}
%
\newenvironment{foreword}{\chapter*{\forewordname}}
   {\par\vfil\null}

%************************* ABSTRACT TITLE ***********************

\renewenvironment{abstract}{\chapter*{\abstractname }
\begin{center}
%{\LARGE\abstractname}}
{\textbf{}}\end{center}}
   {\par\vfil\null}

\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{\chapter*{\ackname}}
   {\par\vfil\null}
%
\newenvironment{ozet}{\chapter*{\ozetname }
\vspace{-0.cm}
\begin{center}{\large \textbf{}}\end{center}}
   {\par\vfil\null}
%
\newenvironment{symbols}{%
   \clearpage
   \chapter*{\listsymbolname}
   \beginsymlist}
  {\closesymlist}
%
\newcommand{\beginsymlist}{%
   \begin{tabbing}
   \hspace*{\symtabi}\=\hspace*{\symtabii}\=\kill}
%
\newcommand{\closesymlist}{\end{tabbing}}
%
\newcommand{\sym}[2]{\>#1 \>#2 \\}
\newlength{\symtabi}
\newlength{\symtabii}
\setlength{\symtabi}{1em}
\setlength{\symtabii}{10em}
%
\newcommand\prefacename{\vskip-0.2cm \hskip -0.65cm\fontsize{16}{1} \textbf{ PREFACE}}                                                            
\newcommand\forewordname{\vskip-0.2cm \hskip -0.65cm \fontsize{16.5}{1} \textbf{ APPENDICES}}
\newcommand\ackname{\vskip-0.2cm \hskip -0.65cm \fontsize{16.5}{1}  \textbf{ACKNOWLEDGMENT}}
\newcommand\ozetname{\vskip-0.2cm \hskip -0.65cm \fontsize{16.5}{1}  \textbf{\"OZ}}
\newcommand{\listsymbolname}{\vskip-0.2cm \hskip -0.65cm\fontsize{16.5}{1}   \textbf{LIST OF SYMBOLS}}
%\renewcommand\indexname{\vskip-0.5cm \hskip -0.65cm\fontsize{16}{1}   \textbf{INDEX}}
\renewcommand\partname{\vskip-0.5cm \hskip -0.65cm  \fontsize{16}{1}  \textbf{PART}}
\renewcommand\appendixname{\vskip-0.2cm \hskip -0.65cm \fontsize{16.5}{1}  \textbf{APPENDIX}}
\renewcommand\abstractname{\vskip-0.2cm \hskip -0.65cm  \fontsize{16.5}{1}  \textbf{ABSTRACT}}
%
% Sectional Units
%
\renewcommand\chapter{\clearpage
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindenttrue
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
%
\renewcommand\@makechapterhead[1]{\begin{center}
  {\fontsize{16}{1}
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \ifx\@app\empty
        \vspace*{-0.8cm} \bfseries Chapter \hspace{0.5ex}\arabic{chapter} \\[0.95cm]    %this line is used to set the chapter head margin in the first \vspace(i did \vspace{-1.98} corresponds to 3.5 cm top margin) and and the end of line\\[cm] is used to set the indent between chapter head and title that should be 24 pt which is aproximately 0.65cm  after indent \\
        %\large\bfseries \hspace{1ex}
    \else
        \vspace*{-0.5cm}\large\bfseries \appendixname\ \thechapter.\hspace{1ex}
    \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip\baselineskip
  }\end{center}}
%
\renewcommand\@makeschapterhead[1]{\begin{center}
  { \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \vspace*{-1.5cm}\large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak                                %fo
    \vskip\baselineskip
  }\end{center}}
%
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                      \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                      \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter}%
                      \ifx\@app\empty
                        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                            {\protect\numberline{\chaptocapp}#1}%
                      \else
                        \addtocontents{toc}{%
                        \noindent
                        \appendixname\ \thechapter\hspace{1.6ex}#1
                        \nobreak\leaders
                        \hbox{$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu\mkern
                              \@dotsep mu$}
                        \hfill \nobreak
                        \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss \thepage}\par}
                      \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                   }
%
\renewcommand\@schapter[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
     \@makeschapterhead{#1} \@afterheading}
%
\def\chaptocapp{\thechapter}
%
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                    {7pt} %{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
                                    {7pt} %{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                    {\fontsize{14}{1}\raggedright\bfseries\textbf\large}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                    {7pt}%{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                    {7pt}%{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\raggedright\bfseries\textbf\normalsize}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection[1]{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {7pt}%{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {-0.5em}%
                                     %{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     %{-1em}%
                                     {\normalsize}[#1]{\underbar{#1.}}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%]
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
%
% There should be a period after the section number.
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
   \let\@svsec\@empty\else
   \refstepcounter{#1}
   \ifnum#2=3
     \edef\@svsec{\underbar{\csname the#1\endcsname\hskip 0.5em}}
     \else
     \edef\@svsec{\csname the#1\endcsname\hskip 0.5em}\fi
   \fi
   \@tempskipa #5\relax
   \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
      \begingroup #6\relax
         \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}{\interlinepenalty \@M #8\par}%
      \endgroup
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}
         {\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
          \else \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}
          \fi
          #7}
   \else
      \def\@svsechd{#6\hskip #3\relax  %% \relax added 2 May 90
         \@svsec #8\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth.\fi
         \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}
         \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}
           {\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
            \else \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}
            \fi
         #7}}
   \fi
   \@xsect{#5}}
%
% First paragraf of a section should be indented
%\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{\if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
%   \par \@tempskipa #4\relax
%   \@afterindenttrue
%   \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@ \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \fi
%   \if@nobreak \everypar{}\else
%     \addpenalty{\@secpenalty}\addvspace{\@tempskipa}\fi \@ifstar
%     {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}{\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
%
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\addtocounter{tocdepth}{1}
%
% Figures and Tables
%
\renewcommand\listfigurename{\vskip 0.85cm \hskip -0.65cm \fontsize{16.5}{1} \textbf{LIST OF FIGURES}}
\renewcommand\listtablename{\vskip 0.85cm \hskip -0.65cm  \fontsize{16.5}{1} \textbf{LIST OF TABLES}}
\renewcommand\figurename{Figure}
\renewcommand\tablename{Table}
%
\renewcommand\listoffigures{% \ev is used for temporary storage of \parskip
\setlength{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}  % This is where the linespacing is changed in the list of tables. Aykut Hocanin
\setlength{\ev}{\parskip}
\parskip0pt
    \chapter*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\listfigurename}%
              {\listfigurename}}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
\parskip\ev}

\renewcommand\listoftables{% \ev is used for temporary storage of \parskip
\setlength{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\ev}{\parskip}
\parskip0pt
    \chapter*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{%\vspace{-2cm}
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\listtablename}}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
\parskip\ev}
%
% The expressions 'FIGURE' and 'TABLE' also appear in the LOF and LOT.
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{\par\addcontentsline{\csname
  ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}{\protect\numberline{
  \csname #1name\endcsname \space
  % This is where the linespacing is changed in the list of tables. Mohammad Ahmad
%  \csname the#1\endcsname .}{\ignorespaces #2}\protect\vspace{\baselineskip}}\begingroup
  \csname the#1\endcsname }{\ignorespaces #2}\protect\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}}\begingroup

    \@parboxrestore
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
%
% A period should appear after the caption number.
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1. #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \centering{#1. #2}\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
%

% The lines of LOF and LOT must not be dotted.
\renewcommand\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{6em}}
\renewcommand\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{5.8em}}
\def\@undottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{\ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
  \vskip \z@ plus.2\p@
  {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
    \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
   \interlinepenalty\@M
   \leavevmode
   \@tempdima #3\relax \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \hbox{}\hskip -\leftskip
   #4\nobreak\leaders\hbox{}\hfill \nobreak
   \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hfil\reset@font\rm #5}
 %  \\*[-2cm]
   \par}\fi}


%
% Table of Contents
%


%\renewcommand\contentsname{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
%\renewcommand\tableofcontents{% \ev is used for temporary strage of \parskip
%\setlength{\ev}{\parskip}
%\parskip0pt
%  A line as 'TABLE OF CONTENTS' must not appear in the
% Table of Contents. Hence we reproduce the \chapter* here except that
% no entry is put into the toc file
%     \clearpage  \global\@topnum\z@
%     \@afterindenttrue
%     \@makeschapterhead{\contentsname} \@afterheading
%\@starttoc{toc}%
%\parskip\ev}
%

\renewcommand\contentsname{\vspace{-0.45cm}\fontsize{16.5}{1}\textbf{TABLE OF CONTENTS}\vspace{-1.2cm}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{% \ev is used for temporary storage of \parskip
\setlength{\ev}{\parskip}
\parskip0pt
%  A line as 'TABLE OF CONTENTS' must not appear in the
% Table of Contents. Hence we reproduce the \chapter* here except that
% no entry is put into the toc file
     \clearpage\global\@topnum\z@
     \@afterindenttrue
     \begin{center}
      { \normalfont
       \interlinepenalty\@M
       \vspace*{-0.2cm}\large \bfseries  \contentsname\par\nobreak
       \vskip\baselineskip \vskip\baselineskip % *********** bir vskip fazladan koyduk
      }\end{center}
     \@afterheading
     \@starttoc{toc}%
\parskip\ev}


% EMU IGER style TOC does not have bold lines
\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    %EMU IGER style TOC does not have extra space between chapterlines
    \vskip 0.5em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode % That is what we have to comment out: \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\leaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu.\mkern \@dotsep
       mu$}\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
%
% The spacing of the TOC lines has been redefined.
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{5em}{2.em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{2.9em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{7em}{3.8em}}
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{11.1em}{4.7em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{16.1em}{5.7em}}
%
% Appendix
%
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
 \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \renewcommand\@chapapp{\appendixname}
  \renewcommand\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}%
  \let\@app1
}
%
% References
%
%\def\@biblabel#1{#1.} % This removes the square brackets AH
%
\newenvironment{harvardbibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}%
     \begin{list}{}{\topsep0pt \leftmargin2em \rightmargin0pt
     \item indent-2em \item sep\parskip \parsep0pt}}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `harvardbibliography' environment}}
      \end{list}}
%
\newenvironment{bibnotcited}[1]{\chapter*{\bibncname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `bibnotcited' environment}}%
      \endlist}
%
\newenvironment{harvardbibnotcited}{\chapter*{\bibncname}%
     \begin{list}{}{\topsep0pt \leftmargin2em \rightmargin0pt
     \itemindent-2em \itemsep\parskip \parsep0pt}}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `harvardbibnotcited' environment}}%
     \end{list}}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\vskip -0.1cm \hskip -0.65cm \fontsize{16.5}{1}\textbf{ REFERENCES}}
%\newcommand{\bibncname}{\vskip-1.3cm \hskip -0.65cm REFERENCES NOT CITED}
%
% Footnotes are numbered consecutively throughout the
% whole thesis and single line-spacing is invoked
%
\def\footnote#1{%
   \@ifnextchar[{\@xfootnote}{%
\setcounter{footnote}{\value{thsfootcnt}}%
\addtocounter{thsfootcnt}{1}%
   \stepcounter{\@mpfn}%
     \begingroup\let\protect\noexpand
       \xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}\endgroup
\let\baselinestretch\@singlespaced
     \@footnotemark\@footnotetext{#1}
\let\baselinestretch\@onehalfspaced}
}
%
% Single line spacing is required in in quotations
%
\renewenvironment{quotation}{%
     \par
     \list{}{%
\let\baselinestretch\@singlespaced
      \listparindent 1.5em%
      \itemindent    \listparindent
      \rightmargin   \leftmargin
      \parsep       \z@ \@plus\p@}%
      \item\relax}
     {\par
\let\baselinestretch\@onehalfspaced
      \endlist}
\renewenvironment{quote}{%
      \par
\let\baselinestretch\@singlespaced
      \list{}{%
       \baselineskip0.67\baselineskip
       \listparindent 1.5em%
       \itemindent\listparindent
       \rightmargin\leftmargin}%
       \item\relax}
     {\par
\let\baselinestretch\@onehalfspaced
      \endlist}
%
% Spacing for displayed formulas (redefine the \normalsize command
% Note: In earlier implementations of LaTeX \@normalsize may need
% to be redefined instead of \normalsize
%
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\@setsize\normalsize{14.5pt}\xiipt\@xiipt
\abovedisplayskip 20pt %\p@ plus3\p@ minus7\p@
\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
\abovedisplayshortskip  \abovedisplayskip %\z@ plus3\p@
\belowdisplayshortskip  \abovedisplayskip %6.5\p@ plus3.5\p@ minus3\p@
\let\@listi\@listI}
%
% Page style
%
\oddsidemargin 1.6cm
\evensidemargin 2cm
\topmargin -1.3cm
%\headheight20pt
\textwidth 146mm
\textheight 249mm
%\pagestyle{myheadings}
%
% Invoke double spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
%
% This is end of emu_tez.sty
```

Comment: BTW, I disable Hyphenation in my whole document and tried;    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\sloppy}   ; But it didn't work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentstyle[12pt,epsfig,EMU_Thesis_ikeV2,amsmath,times,enumerate,tikz,booktabs,slashbox,subfigure,microtype]{report}                 The document class is report. it belong to my thesis.

Comment: In the main document, it is just called by \listofcontents and in the style those file i belive does the job!

Comment: You can edit your question and complete the code there.

Comment: By creating a report class and calling \tablecontents, you may see the above problem (as in the image ) for the long section/subsection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it turned out to be relatively easy.  Note that if there is not enough room on the last line, the page number will be pushed into the margin.  To this end I created `\needhspace` to force a line break when there isn't enough room for the page number (`\@pnumwidth`).

Sorry, but I took one look at your MWE and decided to avoid it.  All you need to do is show the problem.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\makeatletter
\def\@tocrmarg{0pt}
\newcommand{\needhspace}{\rule{\@pnumwidth}{0pt}\hspace{-\@pnumwidth}\null}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\blindtext}

\section{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-3.8em}{1pt}}

\section{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-3.8em}{1pt} \needhspace}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: wow.That's really great.Thank you very much indeed.  It works fine now.

Comment: @user459806: The correct way to thank users for answers is to upvote and accept the answer by clicking on the `checkmark`  left to the answer